# omit edits between quotations " " in sed

Tags: sed

So I have a file which calls multiple sed commands to make many formatting changes to a document.
Is there a way I can make changes to everything except strings within quotations?

for example if I have a line that reads `hello world "hello world" hello world` and a command that changes hello to bye and world to universe in my file, how would I provide the output `bye universe "hello world" bye universe` instead of `bye universe "bye universe" bye universe`?

Also, how would I consider quoted text that spans over multiple lines?

*note* I must do this all in sed

Comment: `echo 'hello world "hello world" hello world' | sed s'/\([^"]*\)\(".*"\)\(.*\)/bye universe \2 bye universe/'`

Comment: yes I understand that works for a single substitution for one line but I dont know what to do if i have many commands that get executed throughout a multiline document and I need to omit quotations before going through all of them

Comment: @vdizzle if you can't extrapolate a solution from your simple example to your 'real world' data, you need to improve your question. Please edit your question to better represent your real world problem and/or provide a sample of your actual data.

Answer (score 2):

This command replaces `hello world` with `bye universe` but **only** if `hello world` is preceded by an even number (like 0, 2, 4, ...) of double-quotes `"`:

```
sed -E ':a; s/^(([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*)hello world/\1bye universe/; ta' file
```

Let's try this on your test input:

```
$ cat file
hello world "hello world" hello world 
$ sed -E ':a; s/^(([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*)hello world/\1bye universe/; ta' file
bye universe "hello world" bye universe
```

Let's try a more complicated test case with multiple quotations.  Here, we replace `one` with `ONE`:

```
$ cat file2
this one said "one." one what? "one sub," he said, one.
$ sed -E ':a; s/^(([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*)one/\1ONE/; ta' file2
this ONE said "one." ONE what? "one sub," he said, ONE.
```

#### How it works

- `-E` turns on *extended* regex syntax so we need fewer escapes.
- `:a` creates a label called `a`.
- `s/^(([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*)hello world/\1bye universe/` does the replacement.  Here `^(([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*)` matches any string starting from the beginning of the line that has an even number of quotes.  Because it is parenthesized, this string is saved as group 1 so that we can reference it as `\1` in the replacement text.
- `ta` tells sed to jump back to label `a` if a substitution occurred.  This causes sed to repeat the substitution command as many times as needed to make all the replacements we need.

#### Compatibility

This code was developed and tested on GNU `sed`.

Comment: Well done. That is slick. The branching on successful replacement is a savior, that is something I often overlook until I see the solution.

Comment: You should mention that'll only work in GNU sed. Even OSX/BSD sed (the other sed version that has `-E`) won't work with that script.

Answer (score 0):

`a file which calls multiple sed commands` usually isn't a great idea, you should probably just be calling awk or similar once. If you want help with that then post a new question.

In any case, for this current question, this will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) sub(/hello world/,"bye universe",$i)} 1' file
bye universe "hello world" bye universe
```